# How to import ToyVpn to android studio and build

Tags: android, vpn

I'm trying to build the android sample code Toyvpn, the code can be downloaded [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn).

But, I don't know how to import code to Android Studio and build. Do I need to create an empty project and modify code manually? I use the Windows version of Android Studio.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to import the project as per the "Import an existing project" section of [this tutorial page](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project). Basically, you just need to click ***File >> New >> Import Project*** and follow Android Studio's new project wizard.

Comment: I imported the project and got many fail message when build. Does the new android studio version not able to import this code?